# Notify me by email when someone is online on gmail

Tags: internet, gmail

I have multiple Gmail accounts some of them I use daily and other on an occasional basis. 
Now lets say I have **2 accounts A and B**  I **want Notification to my A account** when some one is in my **B account chat list  Comes online**?

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: No it is not possible unless you can create a rule which automatically sends an email out from the account to those subscribed on log on.

Comment: why down vote? please explain

Answer (score 1):

You can install [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im) and setup your talk accounts.

Then, go to **Tools** menu, and choose **Bounces** (or contact notifications).
There you choose the account, then the kind of notification you want (for example, when the contact becomes online).

In the **action** frame, you can select what you want to do. Pidgin can automatically open an IM window for you, show some kind of on screen notification, make a sound, send some message to your contact, and even execute some kind of script you build.
My **pidgin** is not in english, so maybe some terms are not exactly as I mentioned them.
But I'm sure you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but this is not what i need actually the question is for the notification even if I am offline to the gmail account the also it should drop me a mail about a user being online on my other gmail account

Comment: @Champ - What you want is not possible.

Comment: why down vote? please explain